# R pairs function - How to change the diagonal values font size?

Tags: r

I have a pairs function in R which is plotting a graphic but the font size is bigger than I would like. Is there any way to reduce it?

Update:

My pairs function:

```
pairs(~erro_O3_s+erro_NO2_s+O3_ref+NO2_ref, data=person.data,
      upper.panel=panel.regression, lower.panel=panel.cor, 
      pch=20)
```

I can change the font size with `cex` but not the diagonals font size.

Comment: Are you wanting `cex.labels` ?

Comment: RE you r edit: `cex.labels` changes the diagonal font size. Using the functions from your previous question: try `pairs(mtcars[1:3], upper.panel=panel.regression, lower.panel=panel.cor, cex.labels=1)` and `pairs(mtcars[1:3], upper.panel=panel.regression, 
      lower.panel=panel.cor, cex.labels=10)` (sorry if i misunderstand)

Comment: That is exactly it mate! Thanks a lot! Put up an answer and I will accept it and upvote it! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cex.labels` changes the diagonal font size.

Using the functions from your previous question: 
try `pairs(mtcars[1:3], upper.panel=panel.regression, lower.panel=panel.cor, cex.labels=1)`

and `pairs(mtcars[1:3], upper.panel=panel.regression, lower.panel=panel.cor, cex.labels=10)`